Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
I am trying to run my unity game in android but it gives following error, please help
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where: Build file 'C:\Users\black\Flappy Potato (Flappy
Aalu)\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\build.gradle' line:
17
What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Gradle'.
Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':classpath'
after it has been resolved.
Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
--info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
0x00007ff65474853d (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff65474d609 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff6557315d1 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007ff655deb00e (Unity)
DebugStringToFile 0x00007ff6537192e8 (Unity)
DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x00000288ea213f83 (Mono JIT Code)
(wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
(UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000288ea213e9b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
(UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x000002891e587910 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log
(UnityEngine.LogType,object) 0x000002895046fdb5 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 0x000002895046fac3 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleInvokationException:ParseAndShowException ()
0x00000289231ec8d3 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks
(UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext)
0x0000028950454633 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess
(UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
0x000002894a2c6043 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess
(UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
0x000002894a2c56f1 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess
(UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
0x000002894a2c5a85 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
<Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object
(object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007ffe99b04c1e (mono-2.0-bdwgc)
mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007ffe99a3d254 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3068)
0x00007ffe99a3d3cc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3115)
0x00007ff654661284 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff65463eff4
(Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff65615f961 (Unity)
CallMono 0x00007ff6561691ad (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x00007ff6561637a3 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild 0x00007ff6561618be
(Unity) DoBuildPlayer 0x00007ff656154b38 (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x00007ff653ecce2f (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00007ff653c0733c (Unity)
BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck 0x0000028921aa36e7
(Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
(string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,string[],bool)
0x0000028921aa2ae3 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer
(UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 0x00000288ea21fbdb (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods
(bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 0x00000289504c103b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons
(UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
0x00000289504b7a43 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
0x00000289504a93db (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI
() 0x00000289126136a2 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI
(UnityEngine.Rect) 0x0000028912613483 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect) 0x00000289125fdb9b
(Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI () 0x00000287acd8c06f
(Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI
(UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000289125aab8b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
(UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
0x00000288ea20109b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
(UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool) 0x00000288ea200ef3 (Mono JIT
Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent
(UnityEngine.Event,bool) 0x00000288ea200a3b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool) 0x00000288ea200923 (Mono
JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool) 0x00000288e22786c3 (Mono
JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x00000288e2278223 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x00000288e2277f5f (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x00000288e2277c53 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase) 0x00000288ea15e933 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x00000288ea53818e (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
0x00000288ea537a5b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x00000288e1269503 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
0x00000288e1269353 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate () 0x00000288e126928b
(Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
0x00000288ea537f33 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
0x00000288ea537333 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x00000288ea53718b (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent
(UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
0x00000288ea541a83 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch
(UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 0x00000288ea541513
(Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent
(int,intptr,bool&) 0x00000288ea5412cf (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
0x00000288ea5411eb (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2
(int,intptr) 0x00000288ea540665 (Mono JIT Code)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
0x00000288ea5407a6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke)
<Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_intptr_intptr&
(object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007ffe99b04c1e (mono-2.0-bdwgc)
mono_jit_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/mini/mini-runtime.c:3445)
0x00007ffe99a3d254 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) do_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3068)
0x00007ffe99a3d3cc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke (at
C:/build/output/Unity-Technologies/mono/mono/metadata/object.c:3115)
0x00007ff654661284 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x00007ff65463eff4
(Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x00007ff654639c05 (Unity)
ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void> 0x00007ff65479288a (Unity)
Scripting::UnityEngine::GUIUtilityProxy::ProcessEvent
0x00007ff655190b54 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00007ff655762b60 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent 0x00007ff655190a83
(Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEventFromAPI 0x00007ff655190958 (Unity)
GUIView::ProcessInputEvent 0x00007ff65576399e (Unity)
GUIView::ProcessEventMessages 0x00007ff65575d7b4 (Unity)
GUIView::GUIViewWndProc 0x00007ffee02aef75 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007ffee02ae69d (USER32) DispatchMessageW 0x00007ff655737103
(Unity) MainMessageLoop 0x00007ff65573c150 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff656b1e76e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007ffee08a7344
(KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ffee22c26b1 (ntdll)
RtlUserThreadStart

I am trying to build and rung my unity game in android but it gives error, I want the game to run in my android device, please help
